# write concatenated dataframe into csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, concatenation, dataframe

I have a directory with dataframes, which I want to concatenate into single one, and write it into csv. So with concatenating, there is no problem, but it seems the problem is with writing. I could explain myself:
I use the following methods for concatenate and write into the csv:

```
path_all = "%all_files" % path
path_sorted = sorted(os.listdir(path_all), key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0]))
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for i in path_sorted:
    f = os.path.join(path_all, i)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
df_all = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
df_all.to_csv('concatenated_df.csv', sep=',')
```

The problem is that when I open the `concatenated_df.csv` I couldn't even separate the columns, all the columns are splitting into one! why it could happen?

Comment: Show the content of `df_all`.

Comment: I think you need define separator  in `df = pd.read_csv(f,index_col=None, header=0)` e.g. `df = pd.read_csv(f,index_col=None, header=0, sep=';')`

Comment: So that others can try to replicate your problem, you need to provide a few rows of your dataframe with three or four columns.  Also, `df.to_csv()` will provide the text output directly to help trouble shoot your issue.  To limit the size of the output, try `df.to_csv()[:100]`

Comment: @jezrael actually it helped! simple and efficient! so you can post your comment as answer!

Comment: @Alexander next time I will provide my data, thank you for your remark! this time one of the proposition in comments worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need define separator in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,index_col=None, header=0)
```

e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,index_col=None, header=0, sep=';')
```